# What is the difference between "PeerAdmin" and "Admin" for an org in Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In Fabric java SDK code, there are two concept for an org:

- PeerAdmin: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java#L312
- Admin: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/End2endIT.java#L315

Could any expert tell me what is the difference between them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two planes of authentication in each Fabric peer/orderer:

- Channel authentication, that is derived from the "channel MSP" which is constructed from the channel configuration (i.e from the genesis block) - Identities that are specified in the channel configuration as admins can perform administrative operations on channels, such as creating new channels, or modifying channels, etc.

  - Local authentication, that is derived from the "local MSP" - Identities that are specified in the local configuration (sampleconfig/msp/admincerts) can perform administrative operations that have no channel context, such as installing chaincodes, and joining peers to channels.

Comment: Thanks. In general practice, the admin of "channel MSP" and the admin of "local MSP" are the same, right?

Comment: It depends on your organization. It may want to separate administration of nodes and administration of application (channel).

Comment: By the way, can I set two or more admin for a local MSP? I mean, put a org's two admin certificates under sampleconfig/msp/admincerts folder?